# Possible to answer a comment made at the Google Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store

Is it possible to answer a comment made in a review at the Google Play Store?

Answer (score 2):

It is now the case that all developers can reply to reviews on their apps. The reply shows up publicly next to the review, and by default, the user who left the review gets notified by email (but users can turn off being notified in the settings on the web). There can only be one reply per review. The reviewer can only respond by editing their review, and the developer isn't notified when this occurs.

It's still not helpful to use reviews for reporting problems with the app, because solving them generally needs several messages back and forth to narrow down the problem, and sometimes needs the user to tell the developer how they were using the app or what they wanted to achieve: something you might not want made public.